# The compiler itself running with parallel computing methodology

Tags: c++, gcc, parallel-processing

Is there GCC compiler that could build large source code in parallel ? "The compiler itself running with parallel computing methodology "
Is there any GCC option for doing the previous requirement?

Comment: You don't really need a parallelized compiler, since no single file is very large. Rather, you want to run many compilers in parallel on multiple files.

Comment: @KerrekSB I wonder if there is any worth in trying to panellize a Unity Build or whether it is always better to not do Unity build when multiple processors available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether gcc has something like that in built, but you have `make` in linux that can run parallel builds using the `-jN` flag

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html